# A network-releated or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I have a simple mvc web site (using the VS internet template) on azurewebsites talking to a SQL Azure database in the same data center.  The database at this time is just to do the built-in SimpleMembership Provider.  I have already switched from the default App_Data mdf file to Azure SQL.  It works fine, but sometimes after a while, it would give:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

with a long message:

> **SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:**
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.
>   The provider attempted to automatically create the application
>   services database because the provider determined that the database
>   does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary
>   to successfully check for existence of the application services
>   database and automatically create the application services database:

But I do *not* have a connection string using SQL Server Express!

Restarting the web site immediately does not remove the error.

Without changing anything and restarting the web site 15 minutes later give:

> **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.**
>
> There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be
>   displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy)
>   contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response
>   from the content server.

Previously, I could restore the website back to working order by just re-publshing from VS.  But for the last hour I have tried and tried and I cannot get the web site to work again.

**What is the problem about SQL Server Express really about?**

My connection string section contains:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:sabl6h4---.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MVC;User ID=test@sabl6h4---;Password=----;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model1.csdl|res://*/Data.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sabl6h4---.database.windows.net;initial catalog=MVC;user id=test;password=----;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Just to be sure, I copied and pasted sabl6h4---.database.windows.net into SSMS and connected using login test and it opened the database without problem.

---

**One day later**:  I created a new azurewebsite and published the exact same project and same web.config.  It works fine without problems.  After some minutes, the exact same error occurred!

---

**Three more hours later**: Went for lunch, came back, hit the browser Refresh button, and the web site is up again. I am convinced that someone is fooling around with the settings at the back end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `<clear/>` element as the first element under the connectionstrings element to ensure no strings are being inherited.  Also, I assume your Azure SQL DB is set up with proper firewall settings allowing your IP where the ASP.net code is deployed?

Comment: Thanks. I added <clear/> and it seems there is a connection string named LocalSqlServer in D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config.  Is this by Microsoft?  It is in the Providers section under AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: I don't think I need that database connection.  How do I delete or avoid it?

Comment: Yes...machine.config is the base config and web.config just extends it.   Which database connection do you mean you don't need?  You can use the remove/ tag to remove any config elements (db config as well).

Comment: Thanks.  I solved my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353901/role-provider-in-simplermembership/19360561?noredirect=1#19360561.  But I am still puzzled why the server switched the SqlMemberShip provider suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error. But in my case I did not notice that the connection string was being overwritten by the publish wizard. I fixed the problem by going to the Settings tab in the Publish wizard and unchecking "Use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)"